# C# and SQL Server: updating trouble with stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-update

Using:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2008
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
- C#
- .NET 4.0
- WinForms

Ok this is my stored procedure. Brace yourself, it's rushed because I have a deadline of 24 hrs and I was told yesterday as I was leaving work (yes I was very annoyed).

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyPareto]
    @pgParam varchar(255)
AS
   SELECT i.pg,
   dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto,
   i.part,
   i.sales6months,
   a.LostSales6Months,
   dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Pareto

FROM
OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT dbo.iLines.Part,
                            dbo.iLines.Pg,
                            SUM(dbo.iLines.Qty) as sales6months,
                            dbo.iLines.Prefix 
                     FROM Autopart.dbo.iLines 
                     where prefix = ''i''
                     and [datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
                     group by 
                     dbo.ilines.pg,
                     dbo.ilines.part,
                     dbo.ilines.prefix
                     order by sales6months desc') i
RIGHT JOIN
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis
on
i.part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part
INNER JOIN
dbo.NewParetoAnalysis
ON
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS =    dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Part

LEFT JOIN
OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT dbo.aLines.Part,
                            dbo.aLines.Pg,
                            SUM(dbo.aLines.Qty) as LostSales6Months,
                            dbo.aLines.Prefix 
                     FROM Autopart.dbo.aLines 
                     where prefix = ''d''
                     and [datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
                     group by 
                     dbo.alines.pg,
                     dbo.alines.part,
                     dbo.alines.prefix
                     order by LostSales6Months desc') a
ON
dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = a.part
/*FULL OUTER JOIN
dbo.NewParetoAnalysis
ON
a.part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Part*/
WHERE
i.pg = @pgParam
GROUP BY
   i.pg,
   dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto,
   i.part,
   i.sales6months,
   a.LostSales6Months,
   dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Pareto
ORDER BY
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto asc
```

Procedure works great, pretty fast too (no idea how hehe). The problem I now have is how to update.

I only want to update 2 tables: `OldPareto` and `NewPareto`.

The data will only come from one column which is the `NewPareto` column. This will update the column in both tables.

Normally its just a simple `UPDATE` call in the code using the `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataSet`.

But since I have this crazy stored procedure I'm troubled as to how this works.

Any C# code you need let me know.

Many thanks!

Comment: How are newPareto and oldPareto tables related to results of this query?

Comment: 1st column in my datagrid is old pareto. old perato and new are just auto numbered (think of pareto as a league of the best selling parts).
new pareto is the same data, but that column will be edited by my boss  for what ever reasons he needs to. Then i need an update query that will update both new and old fields in both tables.  Is that any clearer?

Comment: A long winded way would be too get the new pareto into a new table in my code, then use the table to update my 2 sql tables.  Only thing is its seems a very long way of doing it, so Im hoping theres a quicker solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A long winded way would be too get the new pareto into a new table in
>   my code, then use the table to update my 2 sql tables

Or in sql procedure itself. I still do not understand what are your objects and their relationships, but here is general way to perform similar updates:

First declare temporary table at the beginning of procedure:

```
declare @tmpTable table 
(
  pg int, 
  oldPareto int, 
  part int, 
  sales6months int, 
  LostSales6Months int,
  newPareto int
)
```

obviously, column types do not match yours so you will need to type them properly.
Perform insert into using your select:

```
insert into @tmpTable 
     (pg, oldPareto, part, sales6months, LostSales6Months, newPareto)
     select ...
```

And then perform updates:

```
update oldPareto
   set oldPareto = a.oldPareto,
       newPareto = a.newPareto
  from oldPareto
    inner join @tmpTable a
       on ... -- However you join oldPareto table with results of query

update newPareto
   set oldPareto = a.oldPareto,
       newPareto = a.newPareto
  from newPareto
    inner join @tmpTable a
       on ... -- However you join newPareto table with results of query
```

Comment: that seems amazingly simple and nicely done.  Many thanks thats took a load of my mind, ill get started and update you if I get stuck/complete it.

Comment: might sound silly but where will the update go? new sql statement or within the same proc? if within same proc then where about? would it be at the very end? (sorry if this seems like a daft question but as you probably can tell SQL is not my strong side)

Comment: oh and by the way, once i update my temp table, how will that update the tables that need updating, oldpereto and newpareto?

Comment: Updates go after insert...select part. But you should first create a copy of the procedure or save it to file to be able to compare/revert possible mistakes.

Comment: The results of query are inserted into temporary table. This table is later used to match and update rows in oldPareto and newPareto. Note `inner join @tmpTable a` in two updates.

Comment: Big problem , boss has turned round and said that he does not want any temp tables being used........i said ok what if it is a new table and i update that.  he said no.
Sooooo im very annoyed and will have to resort to the other way.

Comment: This temp table exists during execution of this procedure only. And it is private temporary table, visible only by this procedure. It is quite legitimate approach.

Answer (score 0):

Write a PL/SQL code below the "dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto asc"

eg: UPDATE OldPareto,NewPareto SET OldPareto.NewPareto = 'value' ...

refer this :-

[http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0140__Insert-Update-Delete/Updatetwotablesinoneupdatestatement.htm]

Comment: just noticed that, darn.  any more suggestions ?